# NodeJS App path broken in Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, path

I got this strange issue when trying to run my NodeJS App inside a Docker Container.

All the path are broken 
e.g. :

```
const myLocalLib = require('./lib/locallib.');
```

Results in Error:

> Cannot find module './lib/locallib'

All the file are here (show by ls command inside the lib direcotry)

I'm new to Docker so I may have missed something in my setup

There's my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
COPY out/* out/
COPY src/.env.example src/
COPY package.json .
RUN yarn

ENTRYPOINT yarn start
```

Per request : File structure 
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: can you share your folderstructure, especially the file structure?

Comment: @hereandnow78 Added a screenshot of the file strcuture, main file is dibot.js which require files from lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `COPY` command wrong. It should be:

`COPY out out`